# how to format date and time from JDateChooser to mysql datetime column

Tags: java, mysql, simpledateformat

I am trying yo store current date and time from JDateChooser to mysql database, but it inserts only todays date and current time is 00:00:00

```
  java.util.Date dt1,dt2;     
  String n=name.getText();
  String i=id.getText();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  dt1=jDateChooser1.getDate();
  dt2=jDateChooser2.getDate();
  String strdtver1=(String) sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());
  String strdtver2=(String) sdf.format(jDateChooser2.getDate());

  try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing","root","");
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    String sql="Insert into ss values('"+(n)+"','"+(strdtver1)+"','"+(strdtver2)+"','"+(i)+"');";
    stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "RECORD ENTERED SUCCESSFULLY");

  } catch(Exception e) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
  }
```

It is a program to store check in & check out date and time.
The datatype in mysql is datetime for  Check_in and Check_out.
The data entered in my sql at column Check_in is  2014-10-27 00:00:00. The current date is correct but i want to insert current time instead of 00:00:00.Please help me.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Please use a `PreparedStatement` instead

Answer (score 4):

Your are formatting the dates you get from widgets using [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but you only use a date pattern as a format string; for date and time string format supported by mysql, use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not convert your Date objects to Strings.  Instead, pass them to a PreparedStatement:

```
try (PreparedStatement statement =
    con.prepareStatement("insert into ss values ?, ?, ?, ?")) {

    statement.setString(1, n);
    statement.setDate(2, dt1);
    statement.setDate(3, dt2);
    statement.setString(4, i);

    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Also, using a PreparedStatement is highly recommended when storing user data, as it prevents a serious malicious attack vector known as [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  (Imagine if the user entered his name as `', null, null, null; delete from ss; insert '`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void calendarExpale(){
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    final JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
    JDateChooser chooser = new JDateChooser();
    Date d1=(Date)chooser.getDate();

   chooser.setSize(15, 10);
  chooser.addPropertyChangeListener("date", new PropertyChangeListener() {
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

    JDateChooser chooser = (JDateChooser)evt.getSource();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
    textField.setText(formatter.format(chooser.getDate()));
}
});

 content.add(textField);
  content.add(chooser);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way I have ever used. You do not need to do any extra thing .

```
statement.setString(2,((JTextField) jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```